# How can I make a table cell not stretch when another cell spans 2 rows?

Tags: html, css, html-table

**Info:**

I am creating a ticket type of table for a project but I am struggling to not make some cells stretch.

**JSFiddle:**

If the description is too long, the `ACTIVE` cell gets stretched.

https://jsfiddle.net/7dj7a41d/

I want it to look like this but I also need to be able to have more characters without stretching any other row or column.

https://jsfiddle.net/19Loa5ax/

I have tried playing with `rowspan` and I have also tried moving things around but I haven't been able to find a solution.

Comment: can you set a width on that column? on all columns?

Answer (score 0):

You can set a max width on that td.

```
<td style="text-align:left;padding:0 0 0 15px; max-width: 100px;" rowspan="2">Description goes here, this is now too long......</td>
```

I would also remove the height of your first div, as it does not look good when you shrink the viewport.

```
    height: 102px;  <-- remove this
```

Comment: The max-width still causes the `ACTIVE` cell to get stretched vertically. I want the `ACTIVE` cell to only be one cell, not stretched vertically or horizontally.

Answer (score 0):

I removed some fluff, and separated CSS from HTML, with styling applied using ids (but classes would work just as well).
Next I put the ACTIVE text in a `<div>` and styled it separately.
Finally I removed all the `rowspan`s because they seemed unneeded and did more harm than good.

The result is this:

```css
#divMain {
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid lightgrey;
  border-radius: 15px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  height: 102px;
  margin-top: 25px;
  width: 500px;
}
#table {
  width: 100%;
  height: 95%;
  border-collapse: separate !important;
}
/* Row 1: */
#r1_c1 {
  text-align: center
}
#r1_c2 {
  text-align: left;
  padding: 5px 0 0 15px;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
#r1_c3 {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: blue;
  -moz-border-radius: 0 15px 0 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0 15px 0 0;
  width: 150px;
  height: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
/* Row 2: */
#r2_c1 {
  width: 125px;
}
#r2_c1 div {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: green;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
}
#r2_c2 {
  text-align: left;
  padding: 0 0 0 15px;
}
#r2_c3 {
  width: 150px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="divMain">
  <table id="table">
    <tr>
      <!-- Row 1: -->
      <td id="r1_c1">1</td>
      <td id="r1_c2">Title Here</td>
      <td id="r1_c3">Water</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <!-- Row 2: -->
      <td id="r2_c1">
        <div>ACTIVE</div>
      </td>
      <td id="r2_c2">
        <div>Description goes here, this is now no problem anymore.</div>
      </td>
      <td id="r2_c3">
        <input type="button" value="Close" />
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```